Convert Gaussian Splatting .ply file to Unity compatible file format
I created a .ply file with the following project and import it to this viewer the results are amazing!
I wondered how to import it to Unity preserving the quality. The file formats supported in Unity are mesh files, e.g. .fbx, .obj. etc. I tried to use different online and Python converters to create .obj file, but the results were not close to what I see when importing the .ply to the viewer.
Is there a method to convert .ply files to a format supported by Unity without relying on external plugins? Despite knowing about existing plugins for importing .ply files into Unity, I prefer not to utilize external plugins. I recently came across a Stack Overflow question from a decade ago discussing this topic. I'm curious if any new methods or solutions have emerged since then, or if this capability is still unavailable.
